# Where are filed pulled by git from GitHub located?

Tags: git, github

I work in Windows. I have a GitHub repository containing only one file, helloWorld.txt. I have created a new git repository in my local computer, using the "git init" command, inside some folder "test" - and pulled the above mentioned GitHub repository. Where is the helloWorld.txt file located now? How can I open it with notepad and edit it?

Comment: It's in the folder where you created the repository.

Comment: did you set the remotes correctly after doing a git init? why did you have to do an init in the first place if the repository already existed?

Comment: Can you please post the git commands you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will be present in your repository directory ("test" in this case).

If it is not present make sure you `git clone`d or `git pull`d the repository properly.

ex:

```
cd ~/dev/test
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:myUsername/myRepo.git
git pull origin master
cat helloWorld.txt
```

Alternatively

```
cd ~/dev/test
git clone git@github.com:myUsername/myRepo.git .
cat helloWorld.txt
```

Comment: 2nd example is wrong. Clone would have put it into a 'myRepo' sub dir, so the cat would have to be `cat myRepo/helloWorld.txt` or `cd` into that dir.  Also OP said "on windows"...

Comment: All of these commands work just fine on windows 7 with git bash installed. I'll fix that clone one thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Ah yes I forget that git bash adds those commands. I usually do mine in Powershell/poshgit, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Explain what "and pulled the above mentioned GitHub repository" means. If you had a GitHub repository already, then you didn't need to run `git init`, just `git clone <url>` and it will get your files into a directory underneath where you ran the command that as the same name as the repo

```
cd C:\projects
git clone git@github.com:user/some-repo
cd some-repo
// your files are now here in C:\projects\some-repo
```